# How to make plugin of my nodejs chat app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, plugins, socket.io

I made a chat app using node.js, express and socket.io. Now I want to enable  Plugin of my chat app. So that others can connect my chat app from their web sites. Like Customer Chat Plugin of Facebook. People Simply paste the code snippet into their website code and able to connect and load my chat app.

How could I config my app for this type of plugin and make a plugin like Facebook Customer Chat Plugin?

Please tell me the way how could I enable such a feature..

--Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess that with a plugin you mean a library or a package. You should firstly understand that every package or library out there is just code, that someone writes to make other's life easier -so as not to reinvent the wheel- and it simply consists of functions and classes. When a developer uses a library, he/she just import the function from it. Libraries that thousands of developers use daily are open-source and available to look at their code on GitHub. For example, if Stipe wants their clients to use a library specific for making transactions, they will develop and pack their code and put it in one repository, which can be downloaded so that to import various functionalities and make things easier for us.

I hope that helps, at least just a little bit to have a clearer look at what really libraries or packages that developers use daily are.

Comment: Yes I understand. But I want to know how facebook enable such a feature. For example, I have a web site where I want to integrate facebook chat through plugin.For this Facebook offer a plugin called Facebook Customer Chat Plugin. Now I want to enable such a feature in my chat app. How could I do this?

Comment: So you want to interact with Facebook Customer Chat on your app or to implement a same solution for others to use?

Comment: I want to implement a same solution in my app for others  to use

Comment: Then, I am sorry. I have not really explored chat apps. Try watching some YouTube videos. But if you are not in a large business with more than 100,000 users, I am sorry but it is not worth the effort and your time that you could spend somewhere else (e.g. marketing)

Comment: It's okay..No problem.